# Prove that this is a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I have a question:

[image]

I know the requirements of being a norm(the 3 requirements).I try to use them but,I don't know how to do.Can I get a litle help? Thank you.

Comment: for a) the triangle inequality seems to fail.  b) may be a norm.

Comment: It's a lot easier to look at the homogeneity of a)

Comment: @zapdos there is very little standing between you and the solution. If you know the threes conditions, what is preventing you from checking them? Is there one in particular giving you trouble?

Comment: Ok,I am trying to do somethings on paper.But it doesn't go well.I really don't get it,for example,if t=pi, f=-a.So ||c.f|| = |c|.||f|| = c|a|. So? :D I don't know what I found.

Answer (score 1):

For a), you can check that
$$
\| 2\times (t\to \cos t) \| = 2^2 \neq 2 = |2| \times \| (t\to \cos t) \|
$$

For b), check step by step the definition of the norm.